# Slicing Pandas DataFrame every nth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a CSV file, which I read in as a pandas DataFrame. I want to slice the data after every nth row and store the it as an individual CSV.

My data looks somewhat like this:

```
index,acce_x,acce_y,acce_z,grav_x,grav_y,grav_z
0,-2.53406373,6.92596131,4.499464420000001,-2.8623820449999995,7.850541115,5.129520459999999
1,-2.3442032099999994,6.878311170000001,5.546690349999999,-2.6456542850000004,7.58022081,5.62603916
2,-1.8804458600000005,6.775125179999999,6.566146829999999,-2.336306185,7.321197125,6.088656729999999
3,-1.7059021099999998,6.650866649999999,7.07060242,-2.1012737650000006,7.1111130000000005,6.416324900000001
4,-1.6802886999999995,6.699703990000001,7.15823367,-1.938001715,6.976289879999999,6.613534820000001
5,-1.6156433,6.871610960000001,7.13333286,-1.81060772,6.901037819999999,6.72789553
6,-1.67286072,7.005918899999999,7.22047422,-1.722352455,6.848503825,6.8044359100000005
7,-1.56608278,7.136883599999999,7.150566069999999,-1.647941205,6.821055315,6.850329440000001
8,-1.3831649899999998,7.2735946999999985,6.88074028,-1.578703155,6.821634375,6.866061665000001
9,-1.25986478,7.379898050000001,6.590330490000001,-1.5190086099999998,6.839881785,6.861375744999999
10,-1.1101097050000002,7.48500525,6.287461959999999,-1.4641099750000002,6.870566649999999,6.842625039999999
```

For example, I would like to slice it after every 5th row and store the rows indexed 1-4 and 5-9 each in a single CSV (so in this case I would get 2 new CSVs), row 10 should be discarded.
One issue is that I'll have to apply this to multiple files which differ in length as well as naming the newly created CSVs.

Comment: Can you post your code so far? It would be a lot easier to help. Specifically, you indicate you are trying to do something dynamically. How do you know the 'save to file one', 'save to file two', 'discard' rules for each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(round(len(df)/5)): #This ensures all rows are captured
   df.loc[i*5:(i+1)*5,:].to_csv('Stored_files_'+str(i)+'.csv')
```

So the first iteration it'll be rows 0 to 5 stored with name "Stored_files_0.csv
The second iteration rows 5 to 10 with name "Stored_files_1.csv"
And so on...